# How to find UTF-8 codes via LIKE '%\xC2\xA0%'?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, codepoint, exasol

I have a column that contains NO-BREAK SPACE (\xC2\xA0) instead of SPACE and I need to find that rows.

Copy-pasting works:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
FROM TABLE t
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '% %'
```

but using the code points does not:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
FROM TABLE t
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%\xC2\xA0%'
```

How can I find the rows where a colum contains such symbols via \x code points?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE regexp_Like(PRODUCT_NAME, UNISTR('\00A0'))
```

Depending on your database character set you may try `CHR(106)` instead of `UNISTR('\00A0')`

`xC2 xA0` is **not** the code point, it is the binary representation of Unicode character `U+00A0` (No-Break Space) encoded at UTF-8. The Unicode **code point** is `U+00A0` or 160 (decimal)

Comment: Exasol has no UNISTR() and no REGEXP_LIKE. When I use: SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_INSTR(PRODUCT_NAME, CHR(106)) -> "where clause must be a boolean expression". CHR(106) is 'j'?

Comment: @Vega `WHERE regexp_instr(..) > 0` or something would be a boolean expression. Telling data types apart is essential. And understanding error messages.

Comment: Thanks, adding > 0 works but CHR(160) throws "data exception - argument for chr should be between 0 and 127!". So CHR(160) does not work.

Comment: The question **was** tagged with "oracle", that's why I provided an Oracle solution.

Answer (score 0):

Exasol does not support \x escape sequences. "\xC2\xA0" is not a code point, but the UTF-8 encoding of the code point U+00A0 (decimal 160). See https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A0 for more information.

However, you can use [UNICODECHR(...)](https://docs.exasol.com/sql_references/functions/alphabeticallistfunctions/unicodechr.htm):

```sql
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME
FROM TABLE t
WHERE PRODUCT_NAME LIKE '%'||unicodechr(160)||'%'
```

Note that you have to give it the decimal unicode code point. Not the UTF-8 encoding. You can use `select to_number('00A0', 'XXXX');` to convert hex to decimal.

If you absolutely need to use \x escape sequences, you can create an UDF. See https://docs.exasol.com/7.1/database_concepts/udf_scripts.htm for more information.